# Can't change ci_Controller to CI_Controller in CodeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have the following error when calling login.php:

```
Fatal error: Class 'ci_Controller' not found in C:\wamp64\www\zenoir\login.php on line 2
```

After few searches in google, I found the solution that I should to change from ci_Controller to CI_Controller.

Before:

```
class login extends ci_Controller {

function validate_user(){

    $user_id = $this->input->post('user_id');
    $hashed_password = md5($this->input->post('password'));
    .........
    .........
```

After:

```
class login extends CI_Controller {

function validate_user(){

    $user_id = $this->input->post('user_id');
    $hashed_password = md5($this->input->post('password'));
    ..........
    ..........
```

But the problem is still exist, the error still occurs even if I change ci_Contoller to anything (including CI_Controller)!!!

Comment: MD5 is **not** for hashing passwords.

Comment: try as `class Login extends CI_Controller {`

Comment: @Devsi I already tried that see the question please

Comment: @RasoolAhmed First letter of your controller file name should be in capital letter like `Login` not `login`

Comment: the location `C:\wamp64\www\zenoir\login.php` is simply wrong - did you actually read any of the tutorials ? It clearly states under https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/tutorial/static_pages.html - that you should create your controllers inside the _application/controllers_ folder

Comment: @RasoolAhmed please read the sintakonte comment.

Comment: @sintakonte login.php is in application/controllers folder

Comment: @Devsi I tried and the same error is still occurs

Comment: Accordding to your error message it is `C:\wamp64\www\zenoir\login.php` ...

Answer (score 0):

(1.) Your Codeigniter Directory Structure is Wrong, Put all Controller files
     in **Controller** folder like :-
[image]

```
www/
   codeigniter/
        application/
                controller/
                    Login.php
         system/
         ....
```

(2.)

```
class Login extends CI_Controller{


       }
```

in your directory structure open **system->core->controller.php** , you will see the class name is `CI_Controller`

[image]

Comment: so after changing what errors it shown , please post it.

Comment: but I really changed